# kafka metrics missing in micrometer since SpringBoot 2.3.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, micrometer

Upon switching from SpringBoot 2.2.13 to any of 2.3.x - 2.6.x
I no longer have kafka metrics published in micrometer.

I am not using spring-kafka, just manually creating KafkaStreams or KafkaConsumer, but that worked with 2.2.x. Adding the spring-kafka dependency doesn't help. Does anyone know what I have to do to get these back?

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring Boot 2.3 Kafka metrics names have been changed.

```
kafka_consumer_records_consumed_total_records_total -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_consumed_total
kafka_consumer_records_lag_records -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag
kafka_consumer_records_lag_max_records -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag_max
kafka_consumer_fetch_latency_max_seconds -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_fetch_latency_max
kafka_consumer_bytes_consumed_total_bytes_total -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_bytes_consumed_total
kafka_consumer_records_per_request_avg_records -> kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_per_request_avg
kafka_consumer_heartbeat_rate_heartbeats -> kafka_consumer_coordinator_heartbeat_rate
```

If you have custom consumer factories, add  `customizers.orderedStream().forEach(customizer -> customizer.customize(consumerFactory));`

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> customConsumerFactory(ObjectProvider<DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer> customizers) {
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(customConsumerConfigs());
    customizers.orderedStream().forEach(customizer -> customizer.customize(consumerFactory));
    return consumerFactory;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using `spring-kafka` just `new KafkaConsumer(...)` or `new KafkaStreams(...)`.

Comment: I noticed the name change, which is surprising. Why did the names change with SpringBoot? I would think it would be based on the version of kafka itself or the version of micrometer, but it's not. It's frustrating since I have a bunch of established dashboards and alerts in datadog.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are manually creating those components you should manually register them, see [`KafkaMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka) (I'm not sure how this worked in 2.2.x). You can also check how Spring Boot does this in [`KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration.java).

Comment: I'm not sure how it worked in 2.2.x either, it just worked and I never had to think about it, and then it stopped working in 2.3.x. I saw `KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration` but no examples of how to use it in my use case. I did end up using `new KafkaStreamsMetrics(stream).bindTo(registry)` or `new KafkaClientMetrics(consumer).bindTo(registry)` and that does seem to work but finding all cases and manually adding it is less than ideal.

Comment: Yeah, this is what you should do if you want to manually bind them. You can open an issue for Spring Boot and ask there.

Comment: I opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28954